# ASP.NET Membership advantages

Tags: .net, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-membership

What advantages does Membership provide in the case when you have to write custom implementation? Is there any sense to implement membership interfaces or it would be easier to  make your own UsersService with just things you need?

Comment: Well, you'll have to handle the actual authentication scheme yourself -- i.e. an authentication cookie that you read/write to.   But I agree with your sentiment and personally prefer to take ownership of that entire process and avoid ASP.NET membership altogether.

Comment: As I know, authentication cookies are part of Forms Authentication but not Membership (which is based on Forms Authentication).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a matter of doing things their way or writing your own implementation. I find the Membership framework to be pretty well thought out and flexible, so I would write a custom provider, but if you want to do it all on your own, you can as well, though you won't be able to benefit from their interfaces and integration.